# How to remove an element from the two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array as

```
private int numbers[][] ={{ 170, 100 },{ 270, 100 },{ 370, 100 },{ 470, 100 }}
```

Now i am changing there positions using `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));`
Now i want to remove the the first item from the shuffled array i.e if the first item is  `{170,100}` , it must be deleted from the array. For that, i tried to do something like this

```
 List<int[]> points =Arrays.asList(numbers);
 Collections.shuffle(points);
 points.remove(0);
```

but it is throwing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` could anybody help me out to remove the first element from the two dimensional day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code:

```
 List<int[]> points =new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(numbers));
 Collections.shuffle(points);
 points.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
List<int[]> points = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its written in the API of [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

You cannot modify the returned list. What you can do is to employ [Masud's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423675/1256583).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Arrays.asList returns a List which is privately declared in Arrays class.

```
 private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
```

and doesn't implement modification operations, thus yuo're getting

```
public E remove(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

from it's superclass AbstractList.

As Reimeus suggested: wrap it into java.util.ArrayList or LinkedList